# MongoDB filter out entries that have field value impossible to be parsed to integer

Tags: python, mongodb, filter

I am new to MongoDB. I have a data set that consists of field called 'page' which value is given as a string, e.g. '153'. I want to filter out all the entries which page field value that cannot be parsed to integer, so for instance value like 'page 25'. How do you go about doing this? I know if I use $toInt this will change strings to integers, but when it cannot it will throw an error. I am using Python btw.

```
db.collection.find({'page':{'$toInt':'$page'}})
```

This converts to integer all the parseable strings but throws out error when it cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $ne: [
      "int",
      {
        $type: {
          $convert: {
            input: "$page",
            to: "int",
            onError: null,
            onNull: null
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

**Mechanism:**

- `$convert` takes `$page` to integer or null
- `$type` takes retrieves either "int" or "null"
- if type is null (or not converted to number), then it's retrieved.

Basically, Anything that can't be converted goes to null.

---

Atlas aggregation translates to this, and could also be good:

```
pipeline = [
    {
        '$match': {
            '$expr': {
                '$ne': [
                    'int', {
                        '$type': {
                            '$convert': {
                                'input': '$page', 
                                'to': 'int', 
                                'onError': None, 
                                'onNull': None
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lbMhK6fS_7v)

Comment: Sorry, it does what I need but it does not want to run in Python - I am getting 'NameError: name 'to' is not defined'...

Comment: updating to try something else @kikatuso

Comment: I think it was actually just due to lack of commas...'input', 'to' etc. should all be in commas in Python, so I think that's the case

Comment: @kikatuso alright. but the other one should work too. I used "Atlas" aggregation pipeline translator, to switch from NodeJS to Python. You may need a variation of "aggregate", but that's you will solve in a second